# Toggle markers visibility on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to toggle my map markers off when I click to turn a heatmap on.

My markers object looks like this:

```
var markers = {
  id: id,
  displayId: displayId,
  latitude: job.geolocation.location.latitude,
  longitude: job.geolocation.location.longitude,
  icon: icon,
  options: {
    title: 'ID: ' + displayId,
    visible: showMarkers
  }
```

I default showMarkers to true:

```
var showMarkers = true;
```

Then in my click handler for heatmap I change `showMarkers` to false:

```
vm.turnOnHeat = function() {
  vm.showHeat = true;
  showMarkers = false;
};
```

However, the markers never disappear. I'm confused as to why `markers.options.visible` never picks up this change.

Comment: Have you tried to use $scope variable instead of local($scope.markers)?

Answer (score 0):

Because the object you are creating is only one instance object. This object is initialized only on initialization and this object is stored in memory. Whenever you access object old object instance will be used.

make object like:

```
var makers = function(){
// code here
}
```

This approach may help you.